# MIGRAR UNA APP ANDROID ANTIGUA PARA QUE FUNCIONE CON ANDROID 10

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una aplicación creada con una versión muy antigua de android de hace unos 5 años aproximandamente, al momento de abrir android studio nuevamente me aparece el siguiente error:

Honestamente aun no entiendo mucho las configuraciones de ANDROID

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-50:19 to override.
```

El problema de que este tratando de actualizar la aplicacion es que dicha APP captura el numero de IMEI pero en ANDROID 10 lei que debo darle el permiso  READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE para poder seguir usando el IMEI
MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pe.gob.senasa.asistencia"
    android:versionCode="27"
    android:versionName="2.7">

    <permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <permission android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/asistencia2"
        android:label="SENASA-Asistencia2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="SENASA - Asistencia"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

BUILD GRADLE

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'pe.gob.senasa.asistenciacentral'
        minSdkVersion 15
        //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 27
        versionName '2.7'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Porfavor su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu aplicación debería funcionar con Android 10, de acuerdo a la configuración en el archivo `build.gradle`, pero de acuerdo a el mensaje de error, estas haciendo uso de libraries de soporte (revisa las dependencias), deberías migrar a Android X tu proyecto y asegurar que las library también usen AndroidX:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
> value=(**android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory**) from
> [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
> AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
> is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
> value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-50:19 to override.

Para migrar tu proyecto a AndroidX ve al menú Refactor y selecciona la opción "Migrate to AndroidX":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias me funciono ya no aparece el mensaje de error pero ahora tengo otro problema

Comment: Cual es @LuisEnriqueUríasHernandez ?, si deseas realiza otra pregunta para separar este nuevo problema.